# QFuture<void> detect exceptions

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, exception, qt5

I was using a QFuture<void> with QtConcurrent::run to run some code in a background thread. I want to detect exceptions in this background code from the main thread.

According to [Notification about exceptions in QtConcurrent::run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727506/notification-about-exceptions-in-qtconcurrentrun/13732080) exceptions are re-thrown when you request the result of the future. Unfortunately QFuture<void> does not have the result functions.

I can work around this by making my function return an int, then using QFuture<int> instead of QFuture<void> but adding a return value just to be able to detect exceptions seems a bit perverse.

Is there a way to detect exceptions with a QFuture<void>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, while the QFuture<void> does not have a "result()" function it does have a "waitForFinished()" function that can be used for this purpose.